# Proving that $5^n - 1$ is divisible by $4$ by mathematical induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have done it, but I am not sure that the inductive step is right. Can anybody please clear me about it?

Basic steps as:

Taking $n=1$: $p(1)=5-1=4$.

Inductive hypothesis:  Assume the statement is true for $p(k)$.  $5^k - 1$ is divisible by $4$.

Inductive steps: We must show $p(k+1)$ is true when $p(k)$ is true.
\begin{align*}
& 5^k -1 + 5^{k+1} -1\\
& 5^k -1 + 5.5^{k} -1\\
& (5^k -1) + 4
\end{align*}

Comment: Kindly use MathJax for Math formatting. You can find tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your last line does not make sense.  Perhaps I misunderstood what you intended to write because of your formatting.  Please check that I have not introduced an error in attempting to edit your work.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is $$5^{k+1} - 1 = 5\cdot 5^{k} - 1 = 4\cdot(5^k) + (5^k - 1)$$ 
We have $4\cdot(5^k)$ is obviously divisible by $4$ and $5^k - 1$ is divisible by $4$ by inductive hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

1. For n=1 the statement is true.
2. Assume that $$5^n-1$$ is divisible by 4.
3. Let us consider $$5^{(n+1)}-1$$. We have to prove that it is divisible by4 also.

We have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  5^{n + 1}  - 1 = 5 \cdot 5^n  - 1 = 5 \cdot 5^n  - 5 + 5 - 1 =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = 5\left( {5^n  - 1} \right) + 4 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Since by inductive step 2 you have that $$5^n-1=4k$$ whit k integer you have that
$$
5\left( {5^n  - 1} \right) + 4 = 5 \cdot 4k + 4 = 4\left( {5k + 1} \right)
$$
and this prove step 3

Answer (score 1):

$$ 4|5^0-1=0 $$

and, for integer $\ n>0\ $ we have

$$ 5^n-1\ =\ (5^n-5^{n-1}) + (5^{n-1}-1)
    \ =\ 4\cdot 5^{n-1} + (5^{n-1}-1) $$

where $\ 5^{n-1}-1\ $ is divisible by $\ 4\ $
by induction.